# Sitemap for hundred thousands Posts WordPress Site

Tags: sitemap

I have a WordPress site with 100,000+ posts. I can create a sitemap with Yoast. but they also recommend only to add 1000 posts to sitemap because of efficiency.

How to add a sitemap for my website without issue?

(Withing next year posts count may be nearly 250,000 also)

Comment: I suggest using yearly or monthly archives.

Comment: Thanks, but all posts are created by programmatically. All 100,000 posts are created by just 20-30 day.

Comment: Daily archives then, if that's too much hourly is possible. Point being: archives for your sitemaps.